# How to set CardViews from ArrayList in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, cardview

So I'm working with my android app that takes data from firebase, basically a list of cars that I save into an ArrayList of a specific class. I want to show a list of `CardView` with one car object each, in other words, that each card displays the info about that car (model, km, price, etc). I know that the way I should do this is using a ListView in my layout, but I cant get the adapter to work.

The idea is that it shows something like this, but with car photos and stuff:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTKVT.png)

I'm not very familiarized with this type of structure since I started working on it recently, but I think I'm understand how it works. I made the cardview layout model to display each car and tried to make the `ViewHolder` class. Thanks in advice! My code:

`Vehicle` class:

```java
    public class Vehicle {

    int anio, cv, kms, puertas;
    double precio;
    String combustible, foto, marca, modelo, palanca;

    public Vehicle() {

    } //setters and getters are too, but I omitted them
```

My `cardview_template.xml`

```xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/car_photo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home_icon"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/marca"
                android:text="Mercedes-Benz"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/car_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/kms"
                android:text="128000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/car_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/marca"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/precio"
                android:text="2018"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/car_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kms"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Part of the code that's in the method `onCreate()` in mi `MainActivity`:
**I EDITED THE CODE. SEE IN THE EDIT BELOW**

And finally, the class I used for the `adapter`. I think the problem is here:
**I EDITED THE CLASS. SEE IN THE EDIT BELOW**

---

**EDIT**
So following the advices, I changed the ListView with a RecyclerView, but it didn't work neither. I do not get any errors: CardViews simply do not appear in my RecyclerView.

Here's my new adapter class and the new code in the `MainActivity` `onCreate()`

Adapter:

```
public class VehicleListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VehicleListAdapter.VehicleViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Vehicle> mVehicleList;

public static class VehicleViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public TextView mTextView2;
    public TextView mTextView3;


    public VehicleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_photo);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.marca);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.modelo);
        mTextView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.precio);
    }
}

public VehicleListAdapter(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleslist) {
    mVehicleList = vehicleslist;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public VehicleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Links the cardview layout and prepares the ViewHolder
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_template, parent, false);
    VehicleViewHolder vvh = new VehicleViewHolder(v);
    return vvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VehicleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    /*
    *   Links the layout elements with the variables in this class
    *   and put the object values in them
    */
    Vehicle currentVehicle = mVehicleList.get(position);

    //Uses Picasso librarie to set the image in the holder's ImageView
    Picasso.get().load(currentVehicle.foto).into(holder.mImageView);

    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentVehicle.getMarca());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentVehicle.getModelo());
    holder.mTextView3.setText(String.valueOf(currentVehicle.getPrecio()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mVehicleList.size();
}
```

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
(...)
    //Prepares the recycler view and shows the data
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(vehiclesList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

---

**EDIT2**

Ok so I've come across a **very strange** thing. If I put a debug point **anywhere in the `onCreate()`** and then execute the app debugging, it works just fine. I'm completely lost.

[image]
[image]

If I don't do this, it shows like this:

[image]

It **works both in the emulator and my actual phone**.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should use recyclerView instead of ListView.

here is what you missed:

in the onCreate method replace this:

```
VehicleListAdapter adapter = new VehicleListAdapter(this, R.layout.content_main, vehiclesList);
```

with

```
VehicleListAdapter adapter = new VehicleListAdapter(this, R.layout.cardview_template, vehiclesList);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the way I should do this is using a ListView in my layout, but I cant get the adapter to work.

Actually you need to know that Android apps are given with certain amount of RAM to work with, which will be less if you consider handling images. Hence using ListView is not suggested for Image Handling, specially for huge number of images. The solution to this is using **RecyclerView**, instead of **ListView**.

Also if you need to use RecyclerView, you need to extend RecyclerViewAdapter for the Adapter Class, which will have its own ViewHolder, subclass.

RecyclerView is easy to use, but difficult initially. After practising you will get the hang of it.

You can follow this youtube link [RecyclerView + CardView - Part 1 - LAYOUTS AND CUSTOM OBJECTS - Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw9JF55LDzE)

If you still have some queries please comment, I would be happy to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the yt tutorial. However, I still have the same issue: CardViews are not appearing in my RecyclerView. I did exactly what the tutorial said and nothing worked... I'll update the post so you can see my new classes.

Comment: So the error you got is actually simple to debug, if it is what I think it is. Please make a reference to the CardView in the ViewHolder class as well. Add one functionality to it, say cv.setVisibility(true); in the onBindViewHolder() method

Comment: Even if this doesn't workout, try surrounding the setAdapter function with if(mRecyclerView!=null), so that you know that data is present

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. The cards do list if I close and open the application (without killing the process in my phone). The data is present and when I debug, it loads propoerly. I think the problem is that the methoh `onBindViewHolder` doesn't execute when the app is first executed.

Comment: Use Handler to first load the data. First test with fewer number of images of lesser quality (say 3-5 images). Set the adapter, only after the data is completely fetched. To do this, use the `getChildrenCount()` method of DatabaseSnapshot, get the count, and display the list after the fetched list is equal to the number of children. Till this fetching happens, use an indeterminate Progress Bar to show loading animation. A decent image is about 200kB to 300kB, to view with a height of 200dp tp 250dp.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what to do with what you said. I've never used Handler and I'm so lost rn.

Comment: https://youtu.be/TN-CGfzvBhc, check this link to know more about handler and threads. I just told about it to do heavy tasks such as downloading data from firebase in another thread rather than main thread, so that there are no lags.